# Problem accesing a dictionary value on dialogflow fullfilment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using fullfilment section on dialogflow on a fairly basic program I have started to show myself I can do a bigger project on dialogflow.

I have an object setup that is a dictionary.

I can make the keys a constant through

```
const KEYS=Object.keys(overflow);
```

I am going through the values using

```
if(KEYS.length>0){ 
var dictionary = overflow[keys[i]]
```

if I stringify dictionary using

```
JSON.stringify(item);
```

I get:

```
{"stack":"overflow","stack2":"overflowtoo", "stack3":3}
```

This leads me to believe I am actually facing a dictionary, hence the name of the variable.

I am accesing a string variable such as stack and unlike stack3

Everything I have read online tells me

```
dictionary.stack
```

Should work since

```
  JSON.stringify(item);
```

Shows me:

```
 {"stack":"overflow","stack2":"overflowtoo","stack3":3}
```

Whenever I:

- Try to add the variable to the response string.
- Append it to a string using output+=`${item.tipo}`;

I get an error that the function crashed. I can replace it with the stringify line and it works and it gives me the JSON provided so the issue isnt there

Dictionary values are created as such before being accessed on another function:

```
 dictionary[request.body.responseId]={
 "stack":"overflow",
  "stack2":"overflowtoo",
  "stack3":3 };
```

Based on the suggestion here I saw that the properties where being accessed properly but their type was undefined. Going over things repeatedly I saw that the properties where defined as list rather than single values.

Dot notation works when they stop being lists.

Thanks for guiding me towards the problem.

Comment: Please, post the error you are receiving and also run the following with the variable to check the datatype: `
console.log(typeof variableName);` and post the output also.

Comment: I thought I replied yesterday sorry.